# Modular arithematic Equation

Tags: modular-arithmetic, permutations, contest-math

We have an equation:

$a^x+b^x+c^x \equiv m \pmod n $

also given $a,b,c <  y $ what are the total number of solutions of this equation?

Comment: may you tell what is $y$?

Comment: Seems to be the same problem as in an active contest going on right now. Here is a link: http://www.codechef.com/AUG13/problems/CNTSOLS Should this question be answered?

Comment: @Aman: May be not. It is a programming contes, so it may well be that there is no clean formula. Looks ugly, if you ask me. BTW. This should be a comment - not an answer. Flagging a moderator to help it move...

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I could not comment as I do not have 50 reputation.

Comment: @Aman: I realized that. Absolutetly no harm done! We just prefer to have this as a comment. The moderators will make their decision soon. I dare say we all appreciate you bringing the contest-nature of the question to our notice. I don't know myself, if a programming contest problem (which is what this primarily is) should be temporarily locked or not.